# Change the opacity with a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, opacity

I want to toggle the opacity of a div with a checkbox (no js pls)
This is what I have:

```css
    .overlay {background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;}

    #sidebartoggler:checked + .overlay {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler">

    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="navtext">
    <ul></ul>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: That seems to be working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/jc3pz3o2/

Comment: This is working fine right? what else you required?

Comment: Note that in order to keep this working, you cannot add any other `div` in between the `sidebartoggler` and `overlay`. Once you do that, the `+` sign convention you are using will not work.

Comment: Ahh that way my mistake thanks:)

Comment: You can also use `~` If you have elements in between.